# How to Get the Type of Generics in Haxe?

Tags: generics, haxe

I want to use Generics in Haxe with static methods and get the type of  inside the static method.

I want something like the code below:

```
@:generic
class MyClass<T> {
    static var list(null, null):Map<ValueType, Array<Int>> = new Map<ValueType, Array<Int>>();

    public static function myFunction(value:Int) {
        var type = Type.typeof(T);

        if (!list.exists(type)) {
            list[type] = [];
        }
        list[type].push(value);
    }
}
```

The problem here is when I use `var type = Type.typeof(T);` the compiler says `"Unresolved identifier"` for `T`.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I think this snippet doesn't make much sense conceptually, that's far from the only issue here. Class-level type parameters are not available in static fields, `@:generic` classes can't even have static fields to begin with (you would run into that next when trying to instantiate the class). On top of that, `ValueType` is not a valid `Map` key.

Comment: @Gama11 I understand the problems you spotted on the script (thank you), but it does not answer the question. What I need to know is how to get the type of generic inside the static function the code ```var type = Type.typeof(T);``` does not work.

Comment: Well, that's sort of what I was getting at... You can't, because type parameters are not available to static fields.

Comment: @Gama11 thank you for the explanation very useful.